# define a new color in Tcl/Tk (or redefine an existing one)

Tags: canvas, colors, tcl, tk-toolkit, color-scheme

What I'd like to do is to use my own custom color names when colorizing canvas elements, so i can create my own palettes/color schemes/... for data display within a `canvas`.
I want to achieve something similar to what we can do with hightlightColors/... for regular widgets but with different categories.

Right now, I can use [named colors](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/colors.htm) like so:

```
canvas .canvas
pack .canvas
.canvas create rectangle 10 10 100 100 -fill blue
```

However, sometimes I'd like to use `mauve`, but that doesn't exist yet:

```
% .canvas create rectangle 10 10 100 100 -fill mauve
unknown color name "mauve"
```

Using `tk_setPalette` doesn't help me here:

```
% tk_setPalette mauve #ae7181
must specify a background color
```

Of course I *could* just use variables:

```
% set mauve #ae7181
% .canvas create rectangle 10 10 100 100 -fill $mauve
```

...but that quickly gets ugly in my usecase (where the Tcl/Tk-code is generated by another application - and we really don't want to get into the details of when to escape `$` and when not...)

So: Is it possible to define my own colors in Tcl/Tk?

And while we are at it: is it possible to re-define an existing symbolic color? (e.g. turn `red` into `#ff5632`)

should work on Linux/Windows/macOS (ideally with Tcl/Tk>=8.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set of named colours is defined either by the Xserver (if you are using one) or at compile time as a fixed list (on other platforms). There have been proposals for doing custom named colours like we have for fonts, but none of those have ever seen any implementation work done; in at least one case, someone thought that doing the proposal was enough to get other people to implement stuff for him. (The world doesn't work that way!)

If you don't need runtime reconfiguration of named colours, the easiest thing to do is to put the colour you want, probably as a `#ABCDEF` form, in a global variable and then just use that variable:

```
# Defining a colour
set IMPORTANT_COLOR "#FF9090"

# Using that colour
button -text "Important!" -background $::IMPORTANT_COLOR
```

Another approach that allows for more runtime reconfiguration is to use a custom Ttk theme, but programming themes is something that is both quite tricky (it's subtle) and on the list of aspects of Tk that I've never mastered.